# Possible to return all events from a Google calendar using FullCalendar?

Tags: fullcalendar

FullCalendar's clientEvents method returns only the events that are showing on the current page of the calendar. Is there a way to get an array containing *all* the events from a Google calendar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. There is most likely a "better" way to do this, but I'll share a workaround I came up with that seems to get the job done.

In the fullcalendar.js file there is a function called fetchEvents. The first two lines of this function set the variables rangeStart and rangeEnd. Simply reset these variables with date objects defining your desired range.